# How to call Asp.net Web API using HTTP in a bright script?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I created one API in ASP.NET C# Console base. I used the self-host functionality. My Web API for post username and password from bright-script. I test the online tool postman it's working properly. But I don't know how it's used in bright-script please anyone help.

I use the base URL http://localhost:1579/ for hosting

and return name only

```
public string Post([FromUri] string name) 'Also Check the FromBody
    return name;
}
```

I use postman tool following link http://localhost/api/DefaultAPI/ and parameter pass name="ABC" it returns ASP.NET working properly. I know it's possible to roURLTransfer only HTTPS. Now i used HTTP so it can possible to same thing roURLTransfer or apply different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Http and Https, but it should be live url, localhost will not work.

I have also used web API developed using ASP.NET

Example code to call API from ROKU

For GET method

```
readName = createObject("roUrlTransfer")
readName.setUrl("http://example.com/api/defaultapi?name=ABC")
Name=readName.GetToString()
```

For POST method

```
roRequest = createObject("roUrlTransfer")
roRequest.setUrl("http://example.com/api/defaultapi")
roRequest.SetRequest("POST")
roRequest.PostFromString("")
```

Comment: It's fine. But which place to pass argument in the POST Method.

Comment: you gave a Data name = ABC is perfect Because you write in URL. But using a post method how to pass a argument.